# HTTP server on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, httpserver

I am using cocoa http server on iPhone. Its working fine if I set a root document. But I want to list all the contents of my "Document directory". I tried setting the root document to the document's directory path

```
NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *rootDir = [directories lastObject];
[httpServer setDocumentRoot:rootDir];
```

(I tried getting the path programatically)

But its not working ... any idea on this or is there any opensource project that I can use to list the content of my document directory?

Update : here is link to the project ([cocoa http server](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/))

Comment: I can't see anything in the Cocoa HTTP Server source that suggests it supports directory listing. I assume you want something [like this](http://www.css-zibaldone.com/articles/directory/img/apache.png)?

Comment: @micpringle - yes exactly like this.. do you know how can I do this? any opensource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) and it's [Objective-C Wrapper](http://www.crocodella.com.br/2011/06/java-style-servlets-in-obj-c-using-mongoose-server/). It seems Mongoose natively supports directory listing.

Comment: Thanks .. is there any way to display directory listing of a particular directory? –

Comment: You could subclass `MongooseServer` and override `- (id)initWithPort:(int)port allowDirectoryListing:(BOOL)listing` to set the root to a specific directory; it's currently set to*`NSHomeDirectory()`. Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/crocodella/MongooseWrapper/blob/master/MongooseWrapper/MongooseServer.m) of the wrapper on GitHub to see what options need setting.

Answer (score 2):

You must use;

```
NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *rootDir = [directories lastObject];
[httpServer setDocumentRoot:rootDir];
```

because the GUID for the app changes on every install (i.e. the number starting with 8D41 in your dir above).

Comment: (I tried getting the path programatically)... exactly as you posted... any more idea

Comment: its not working means - when I access the server on my mac safari using - http://192.168.0.118:12345 safari not showing anything.. but when I set a file to document root safari showing that file.. hope it helps